# Do you get the Civ 4 "You declared war on our friend" penalty with civs you didn't know at the time?

Tags: civilization-4, civilization-4-beyond-the-sword

Suppose I declare war on the French at a time when I don't know the Chinese. When I later meet the Chinese, might I have a "You declared war on our friend" penalty with them for having declared war on the French?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you will. Additionally you'll also get a "you traded with our worst enemy" penalty in much the same fashion . The latter being more frequent, as it is unlikely to go to war without having met all civs on the continent.